# Retrieve Youtube most viewed, most rated video details using - Google API Client Library for Java

Tags: java, android, google-api-java-client

I have been searching for getting some solution using which I can easily get precise information regarding -

1) Youtube Most Viewed Videos
2) Youtube Most Rated Videos
3) Youtube Search

I know that this can be done with ease using gdata-java-client.

But, my requirement is that, I need to get the aforesaid three details using Google API Client Library for Java (http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/)

Any help which can provide valuable information/ code which will help me get the youtube data precisely, will be well appreciated.

Looking forward for your valuable help, comments, suggestions,

Regards,
Rony

Answer (score 1):

Rony,

Please take a look at the [youtube-jsonc-sample](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/youtube-jsonc-sample/instructions.html?repo=samples&name=dev) that uses the [YouTube JSON-C](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_jsonc.html) feed for searching for videos.

Although it is not an Android sample, the same code should work on Android, except of course for the user interface.

Comment: there is no page found on link you provided