# How to get a list of most-viewed videos on YouTube, including viewcount and date posted

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I want to get a list of the most-viewed videos on YouTube. A lot of websites list the top ten or twenty, but I want a lot more than that. *Wikipedia* gives a list of [the top 30](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_most-viewed_YouTube_videos), which is still not much.

The information below shows that such a list can apparently not be obtained from the YouTube Data API, and apparently not from any YouTube API. The question then is, how can such a list be generated?

The [YouTube documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support) states that StackOverflow is the official venue for support on the YouTube APIs, so I hope we can get an official response from YouTube on what's going on here, as well as responses from knowledgeable folks outside of Google (which owns YouTube).

### MyTop100Videos

The reference given for *Wikipedia*'s list is the playlist, *[Most Viewed Videos of All Time • (Over 450M views)](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLirAqAtl_h2r5g8xGajEwdXd3x1sZh8hC)* from the YouTube channel, *[MyTop100Videos](https://www.youtube.com/c/MyTop10Videos)*. That list currently has 537 videos, which is plenty. But if I want more, the channel has three more playlists that go all the way down to 75M views, a total of 2,051 videos. But the problem with those lists is they don't include the number of views of each video and the dates they were posted, which I need. So, it's a great, comprehensive list, but it doesn't give enough data.

(Actually, in DevTools I see that the date posted is hidden in there, but the number of views is not.)

### StackOverflow search

A search on *StackOverflow* for "YouTube API most viewed videos" brings up the following Q&As:

- 2010: [Retrieve Youtube most viewed, most rated video details using - Google API Client Library for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777531/retrieve-youtube-most-viewed-most-rated-video-details-using-google-api-client)

One answer, which suggests using [YouTube JSON-C](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_jsonc.html), which was apparently part of an old API, because that link now redirects to the [Data API v3 documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples?csw=1).

- 2012: [Youtube GData 2 thousand most viewed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12879754/youtube-gdata-2-thousand-most-viewed)

One answer. What's interesting here is that the problem discussed in the question and the answer was not about getting correct results, but about how long a list of results one can get. The question stated some URLs that were used, which started with `http://gdata.youtube.com/`, which was apparently part of the old API. So it seems that the older API was capable of returning a correct list of most-viewed videos, but that the number of videos returned was limited.

- 2012: [Youtube api get top 10 most viewed with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836609/youtube-api-get-top-10-most-viewed-with-python)

Two answers. Like the previous two Q&As, this was still back in the days of the old API. The questioner was getting the wrong results from `gData`, but then he reported getting correct results when he applied the suggestion given in the accepted answer. However, he said that only worked for a while, and then it started giving him incorrect results again. So did YouTube do something to break `gData` so that it stopped returning correct results for most-viewed videos?

- 2014: [Youtube api v3 : Get Today's, Last week, last month, overall Most Viewed and Most Rated videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21527778/youtube-api-v3-get-todays-last-week-last-month-overall-most-viewed-and-mos)

No answers. The question suggests a call equivalent to the following URL:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id,snippet&maxResults=50&order=viewCount&type=video&key=<key>
```

I ran this and got a list starting with *[Minecraft Live 2022](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iM9KtHaDcUg)*, which has just under 6 million views, definitely not the most viewed YouTube video!

- 2016: [Undeterministic search results with most viewed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41121867/undeterministic-search-results-with-most-viewed)

One answer. This is another interesting situation because the questioner says that he was getting results that were mostly correct, but were missing some videos that should have been included, and that what was left out changed from day to day. He was using the following URL:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&alt=json&type=video&order=viewCount&maxResults=50&key=<key>
```

His result list always started with *[Psy - Gangnam Style](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0)*, which today has 4.6 billion views and might have been the most-viewed video at the time. But when I run that URL, I get a list that starts with *[BTS (방탄소년단) '달려라 방탄 ...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cb70gcTVvYI)*, which has only 4 million views.

Did the Data API give mostly correct most-viewed results in 2016, and has it since been modified by Google to break it so it gives most-viewed results that are all wrong?

The answer suggests using `chart=mostPopular`. The questioner responds to that saying that "most popular" uses an algorithm that isn't the same thing as "most viewed". But even so, when I run the URL:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&chart=mostPopular&key=<key>
```

I get results that start with [(Hebrew title that doesn't paste here properly)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FPsVQDXNtOo), which was posted last year and has only 141,000 views. By what algorithm is that the most popular video on YouTube????

- 2019: [YouTube API How to Get Most Viewed Videos of All Time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55698053/youtube-api-how-to-get-most-viewed-videos-of-all-time)

No answers. The question gives a URL that was tried:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id,snippet&maxResults=10&order=viewCount&safeSearch=none&key=<key>
```

A comment said that that seemed to give the correct result, but I tried it and got a list starting with the same Minecraft video as above.

- 2021: [YouTube API get list of videos with more than n views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70204866/youtube-api-get-list-of-videos-with-more-than-n-views)

One answer, which says you can't specify the minimum views, but suggests using code equivalent to the following URL:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&order=viewCount&type=video&fields=*&key=<key>
```

The questioner responded, saying that when he ran that the result list started with a video that had 50M views. When I ran it, the result was even worse, starting with *[FITKIREE | Nepali Full Movie ...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lo7SH3S6zCw)*, which has just under 4M views.

### Google search

The same search on Google brought up:

- 2021: [How to find find the Most Popular videos with YouTube API C#](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hDkKyAMAobA) and [Find the most Popular videos on YouTube API with Node.JS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rgIyADYS9ys) (both videos)

Those two videos are nearly identical, and it appears they cover implementing the same technique in two different languages. In the C# version, the bottom line is shown at *t* = 6:20 with code that appears to be equivalent to the URL:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&chart=mostPopular&RegionCode=us&key=<key>
```

Here we have same issue as mentioned above, that "most popular" is not the same as "most viewed". It could be that this parameter of popularity may be worth investigating, but it is still very different from the number of views. This is shown by the results when I run the above URL, in which the top result is *[I Will Start an Only Fans...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mOgQDKOGZ1k)*. This was posted just yesterday and already has almost 4 million views, so it definitely qualifies as popular at the level of viral, but it's still nowhere near being the most viewed.

Another problem with this method is that it works for one country at a time instead of worldwide. The instructor in the video says that if the parameter `RegionCode` is omitted, it defaults to `us`. And when I remove that parameter from the URL, it does appear that I get the same results as with the value `us`.

- 2022: [Youtube Data API v3 search.list order parameter working unexpectedly](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/240611709)

This is a bug report submitted to Google just a couple of months ago, complaining about the problems discussed above. The final verdict on the case is:

> Status: Won't Fix (Intended Behavior)
>
> Hello, this is working as intended. The value for "q" parameter is not
> set, so for this request, "site:youtube.com" will be used as a raw
> query. Search endpoint is not intended to retrieve most viewed videos
> in YouTube. Thank you.

I don't understand what they mean by "raw query" and I don't understand what it means to limit a YouTube search to the site youtube.com.

### Conclusion

The bottom line message of the response from Google to that bug report appears to be that YouTube does not intend to help us find out what videos have the most views. They have apparently hacked their code to prevent the API from giving us that. The history above seems to indicate that the old API initially allowed that kind of search, but that is was later disabled. Similarly, it looks like the new API was giving mostly correct results in 2016, but was later changed to return nonsense.

Which raises the question, how does *[MyTop100Videos](https://www.youtube.com/c/MyTop10Videos)* maintain its auto-updated lists of most-viewed videos on YouTube?

### A workaround

Edit: This final section used to be titled "An attempted workaround" because my API URLs weren't working. But I found the bug. If you saw the previous version of this question, the problem was that I wrote:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/video?...
```

instead of:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?...
```

I.e., I was missing an 's'. Once I put that in, the URL worked.

So I have now posted an answer based on that corrected URL. And as I say there, I hope someone else will post a better answer than my klugey solution.

Comment: `[...] But the problem with those lists is they don't include the number of views of each video and the dates they were posted, which I need.` = because you need to use `videos.list` for get specific details of the video. If certain information is not *publicly available*, then, you can't do much about it, tbh. Keep in mind this because any channel owner might decide to hide their comments/views (*even the video*), so, one day might be pubic, the next day, not anymore. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) since YouTube Data API is limited for such specific requirements, I suggest you to work with the data *publicly available* and keep´yourself a database - just in case one of those videos are no longer available or their metadata (*likes, views, etc*) are not available the next time you query those video(s). Next question I have is: `A lot of websites list the top ten or twenty, but I want a lot more than that.` = how much? how you can tell if the response is accurate? against what? - I'm not saying this for invalitdate the requierement or something, but, keep in mind, YT API is limited.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to get the data. It's kind of a kluge, so I hope someone can post a better answer.

What I've done is to take MyTop100Videos' playlist of 537 [*Most Viewed Videos of All Time*](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLirAqAtl_h2r5g8xGajEwdXd3x1sZh8hC), used DevTools to get the playlist's page code, and extracted the IDs of all the videos from that. Then I fed those IDs to YouTube's Data API. I had to do that 50 IDs at a time because giving it more than that yields an error.

(Edit: I found that a better way to get the video IDs, which I used on the next three "Most-Viewed" playlists, is to use the API's `playlistItems`. Since this gives me data on all the videos in the playlist, I was hoping that I could use that to get all the data and not have to feed the IDs back to the API. But a `playlistItems` request doesn't allow most of the `part`s that `videos` does, so I still had to do it in two steps. For the 2,051 videos of all four playlists, I automated the process in Excell VBA, giving me a nice spreadsheet of all the data.)

For an example of the URLs used to get the data, working with just the first three videos in the list, the URL would be:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=XqZsoesa55w,kJQP7kiw5Fk,F4tHL8reNCs&part=snippet,statistics&key=<key>
```

The output of that is:

```json
{
  "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
  "etag": "sd8aQ0bOKfI45PVaPAimq6wzfAM",
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "etag": "XOtjbBdjTHeLG10iEbs2LmdsUp0",
      "id": "XqZsoesa55w",
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2016-06-17T23:00:30Z",
        "channelId": "UCcdwLMPsaU2ezNSJU1nFoBQ",
        "title": "Baby Shark Dance | #babyshark Most Viewed Video | Animal Songs | PINKFONG Songs for Children",
        "description": "⭐️ [NEW CHANNEL] Subscribe  Bebefinn - Nursery Rhymes & Kids Songs ⭐️ \nhttps://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-cY4X2sLECUhishGNiyofQ?sub_confirmation=1\n\nWatch Baby Shark from  Bebefinn: https://link.cleve.re/11982/01\n\nWatch the 10 billion viewed Baby Shark Dance  ➡️https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XqZsoesa55w\n\n\n Subscribe and watch new videos uploaded every week\nhttps://www.youtube.com/channel/UCcdwLMPsaU2ezNSJU1nFoBQ?sub_confirmation=1\n\n❤️Download [Baby Shark Best Kids Songs & Stories app] ⬇\nhttps://fong.kr/119/09\n\n Visit our Official Store:\nhttps://link.cleve.re/10483/\n\nBuy Pinkfong & Baby Shark Sound Books:\nhttps://fong.kr/10826/\n\nJoin BabySharkChallenge Now! \nhttps://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQiKLJnked44qohZMuNHqmYFTOwb07in5\n\nYou are watching the original Pinkfong Baby Shark Dance video. \nJoin Pinkfong's Baby Shark Challenge by uploading your own videos on social media! \n\n----\n★ Lyrics\n\nBaby Shark\n\nBaby shark, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nBaby shark, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nBaby shark, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nBaby shark!\n\nMommy shark, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nMommy shark, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nMommy shark, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nMommy shark!\n\nDaddy shark, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nDaddy shark, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nDaddy shark, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nDaddy shark!\n\nGrandma shark, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nGrandma shark, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nGrandma shark, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nGrandma shark!\n\nGrandpa shark, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nGrandpa shark, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nGrandpa shark, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nGrandpa shark!\n\nLet’s go hunt, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nLet’s go hunt, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nLet’s go hunt, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nLet’s go hunt!\n\nRun away, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nRun away, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nRun away, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nRun away!\n\nSafe at last, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nSafe at last, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nSafe at last, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nSafe at last!\n\nIt’s the end, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nIt’s the end, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nIt’s the end, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nIt’s the end!\n\n----\nSubscribe to PINKFONG's YouTube channel for hundreds of kids' favorite songs and stories, including phonics songs, nursery rhymes, bedtime lullabies, children's classics, fairy tales and more!\n\nEnjoy educational songs and stories for preschool kids created by experts in children's education.\n\nFollow us on Facebook for new updates and free promotions.\n★ Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/pinkfong.official \n★ Instagram: https://instagram.com/pinkfong.official \n★ Twitter: https://twitter.com/pinkfong_usa\n★ Website:  https://www.pinkfong.com/en \n★ Official Merch Store: https://www.amazon.com/pinkfong\n★ Many Thanks to all of our 100 Million Subscribers on Youtube Channels!\n\nPlease take a moment, and participate in a survey for better contents ✅\nWe would love to hear anything from you! \n\n➡️  https://forms.gle/83JN6rvW11oWcB977\n\nSong origin: Traditional Nursery Rhyme \nMusical arrangement by Pinkfong (Smart Study Co., Ltd.), KizCastle\nSinger: Bommie Catherine Han, Hope Marie Segoine, Anipen Matthew Digiacomo, Robert William Gardiner,Charity Wynn Segoine\n\nCopyright © 2016 Smart Study Co., Ltd. All Rights Reserved.\n#babysharkdance #forkids #animalsong #babyshark #nurseryrhymes #pinkfong #kids",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XqZsoesa55w/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XqZsoesa55w/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XqZsoesa55w/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          },
          "standard": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XqZsoesa55w/sddefault.jpg",
            "width": 640,
            "height": 480
          },
          "maxres": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/XqZsoesa55w/maxresdefault.jpg",
            "width": 1280,
            "height": 720
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "Pinkfong Baby Shark - Kids' Songs & Stories",
        "tags": [
          "baby shark",
          "baby shark dance",
          "baby shark song",
          "cute dance for children",
          "dance for kids",
          "baby shark challenge",
          "pinkfong",
          "family",
          "kids",
          "toddlers",
          "babies",
          "videos",
          "kids education",
          "videos for kids",
          "kids videos",
          "kids animation",
          "songs",
          "songs for kids",
          "songs for children",
          "kids app",
          "nursery rhymes",
          "baby shark for kids",
          "baby shark remix",
          "بيبي شارك",
          "shark song",
          "เบบี้ชาร์ค",
          "tiburón bebé original",
          "bebe tiburon",
          "most viewed video",
          "shark family",
          "play baby shark",
          "play baby shark on youtube",
          "baby"
        ],
        "categoryId": "27",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "defaultLanguage": "en",
        "localized": {
          "title": "Baby Shark Dance | #babyshark Most Viewed Video | Animal Songs | PINKFONG Songs for Children",
          "description": "⭐️ [NEW CHANNEL] Subscribe  Bebefinn - Nursery Rhymes & Kids Songs ⭐️ \nhttps://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-cY4X2sLECUhishGNiyofQ?sub_confirmation=1\n\nWatch Baby Shark from  Bebefinn: https://link.cleve.re/11982/01\n\nWatch the 10 billion viewed Baby Shark Dance  ➡️https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XqZsoesa55w\n\n\n Subscribe and watch new videos uploaded every week\nhttps://www.youtube.com/channel/UCcdwLMPsaU2ezNSJU1nFoBQ?sub_confirmation=1\n\n❤️Download [Baby Shark Best Kids Songs & Stories app] ⬇\nhttps://fong.kr/119/09\n\n Visit our Official Store:\nhttps://link.cleve.re/10483/\n\nBuy Pinkfong & Baby Shark Sound Books:\nhttps://fong.kr/10826/\n\nJoin BabySharkChallenge Now! \nhttps://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQiKLJnked44qohZMuNHqmYFTOwb07in5\n\nYou are watching the original Pinkfong Baby Shark Dance video. \nJoin Pinkfong's Baby Shark Challenge by uploading your own videos on social media! \n\n----\n★ Lyrics\n\nBaby Shark\n\nBaby shark, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nBaby shark, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nBaby shark, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nBaby shark!\n\nMommy shark, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nMommy shark, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nMommy shark, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nMommy shark!\n\nDaddy shark, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nDaddy shark, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nDaddy shark, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nDaddy shark!\n\nGrandma shark, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nGrandma shark, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nGrandma shark, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nGrandma shark!\n\nGrandpa shark, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nGrandpa shark, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nGrandpa shark, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nGrandpa shark!\n\nLet’s go hunt, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nLet’s go hunt, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nLet’s go hunt, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nLet’s go hunt!\n\nRun away, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nRun away, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nRun away, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nRun away!\n\nSafe at last, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nSafe at last, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nSafe at last, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nSafe at last!\n\nIt’s the end, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nIt’s the end, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nIt’s the end, doo doo doo doo doo doo.\nIt’s the end!\n\n----\nSubscribe to PINKFONG's YouTube channel for hundreds of kids' favorite songs and stories, including phonics songs, nursery rhymes, bedtime lullabies, children's classics, fairy tales and more!\n\nEnjoy educational songs and stories for preschool kids created by experts in children's education.\n\nFollow us on Facebook for new updates and free promotions.\n★ Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/pinkfong.official \n★ Instagram: https://instagram.com/pinkfong.official \n★ Twitter: https://twitter.com/pinkfong_usa\n★ Website:  https://www.pinkfong.com/en \n★ Official Merch Store: https://www.amazon.com/pinkfong\n★ Many Thanks to all of our 100 Million Subscribers on Youtube Channels!\n\nPlease take a moment, and participate in a survey for better contents ✅\nWe would love to hear anything from you! \n\n➡️  https://forms.gle/83JN6rvW11oWcB977\n\nSong origin: Traditional Nursery Rhyme \nMusical arrangement by Pinkfong (Smart Study Co., Ltd.), KizCastle\nSinger: Bommie Catherine Han, Hope Marie Segoine, Anipen Matthew Digiacomo, Robert William Gardiner,Charity Wynn Segoine\n\nCopyright © 2016 Smart Study Co., Ltd. All Rights Reserved.\n#babysharkdance #forkids #animalsong #babyshark #nurseryrhymes #pinkfong #kids"
        },
        "defaultAudioLanguage": "en-US"
      },
      "statistics": {
        "viewCount": "11518456508",
        "likeCount": "37562167",
        "favoriteCount": "0"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "etag": "PexC7mWdUzBydIw87gPYgy5K1iE",
      "id": "kJQP7kiw5Fk",
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2017-01-13T05:00:02Z",
        "channelId": "UCLp8RBhQHu9wSsq62j_Md6A",
        "title": "Luis Fonsi - Despacito ft. Daddy Yankee",
        "description": "“Despacito” disponible ya en todas las plataformas digitales: https://UMLE.lnk.to/DOoUzFp \n“Imposible” disponible ya en todas las plataformas digitales: https://UMLE.lnk.to/IMPOSIBLEFp\n“Calypso” disponible ya en todas las plataformas digitales: https://UMLE.lnk.to/CLYPSFp\nEchame La Culpa disponible ya en todas las plataformas digitales: https://UMLE.lnk.to/ELCFp\n\n\nBest of Luis Fonsi / Lo mejor Luis Fonsi: https://GooDotGl.com/KLWPSa \nSubscribe here: https://GooDotGl.com/nkhcGc\nSigue a Luis Fonsi: \nOfficial Site: http://www.luisfonsi.com/ \nFacebook: https://www.facebook.com/luisfonsi/ \nTwitter: https://twitter.com/LuisFonsi \nInstagram: https://www.instagram.com/luisfonsi\n\n#LuisFonsi #Despacito #Imposible #Calypso #EchamelaCulpa #NadaEsImposible #NothingisImpossible #LF\n\n\nMusic video by Luis Fonsi performing Despacito. (C) 2017 Universal Music Latino",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/kJQP7kiw5Fk/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/kJQP7kiw5Fk/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/kJQP7kiw5Fk/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          },
          "standard": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/kJQP7kiw5Fk/sddefault.jpg",
            "width": 640,
            "height": 480
          },
          "maxres": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/kJQP7kiw5Fk/maxresdefault.jpg",
            "width": 1280,
            "height": 720
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "LuisFonsiVEVO",
        "tags": [
          "Luis",
          "Fonsi",
          "Despacito",
          "UMLE",
          "Latino",
          "Latin",
          "Pop",
          "Luis Fonsi",
          "Daddy Yankee",
          "Music Video",
          "Oficial",
          "Official Music Video",
          "#Despacito",
          "Zuleyka Rivera",
          "Super model",
          "Miss Universe",
          "Puerto Rico"
        ],
        "categoryId": "10",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "localized": {
          "title": "Luis Fonsi - Despacito ft. Daddy Yankee",
          "description": "“Despacito” disponible ya en todas las plataformas digitales: https://UMLE.lnk.to/DOoUzFp \n“Imposible” disponible ya en todas las plataformas digitales: https://UMLE.lnk.to/IMPOSIBLEFp\n“Calypso” disponible ya en todas las plataformas digitales: https://UMLE.lnk.to/CLYPSFp\nEchame La Culpa disponible ya en todas las plataformas digitales: https://UMLE.lnk.to/ELCFp\n\n\nBest of Luis Fonsi / Lo mejor Luis Fonsi: https://GooDotGl.com/KLWPSa \nSubscribe here: https://GooDotGl.com/nkhcGc\nSigue a Luis Fonsi: \nOfficial Site: http://www.luisfonsi.com/ \nFacebook: https://www.facebook.com/luisfonsi/ \nTwitter: https://twitter.com/LuisFonsi \nInstagram: https://www.instagram.com/luisfonsi\n\n#LuisFonsi #Despacito #Imposible #Calypso #EchamelaCulpa #NadaEsImposible #NothingisImpossible #LF\n\n\nMusic video by Luis Fonsi performing Despacito. (C) 2017 Universal Music Latino"
        },
        "defaultAudioLanguage": "en-US"
      },
      "statistics": {
        "viewCount": "7988478146",
        "likeCount": "49968552",
        "favoriteCount": "0",
        "commentCount": "4243908"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "etag": "wqYjLezeu2g_CN3EI0LT0NmzcmQ",
      "id": "F4tHL8reNCs",
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2016-10-08T07:06:35Z",
        "channelId": "UC4NALVCmcmL5ntpV0thoH6w",
        "title": "Johny Johny Yes Papa  THE BEST Song for Children | LooLoo Kids",
        "description": "Johny Jonhy Yes Papa - best song from LooLoo KIDS Nursery Rhymes and Children`s Songs. Download our music app: http://onelink.to/looloo New game with Johny and Friends - https://3novg.app.link/F2ViI5MeNfb\n\nListen on SPOTIFY  - http://listento.loolookids.com/bestofloolookids\nDownload Lea and Pop app: http://onelink.to/leaandpop\n\nSubscribe to our channel if you enjoyed this educational video! You’ll get constant access to more nursery rhymes, more awesome content, so you’ll never miss a chance to show your children new and exciting things! http://BitDotLy.com/Subscribe_to_LooLooKids\n\nFollow us on Facebook for new updates! https://www.facebook.com/LooLooKids/\nTweet to us! https://twitter.com/loolookids\nInstagram: https://instagram.com/loo.loo.kids\n Watch the LooLoo Kids Playlist:  http://BitDotLy.com/310qEOk\n\nJohny Johny Yes Papa Lyrics\n\nJohny, Johny\nYes, Papa?\nEating sugar?\nNo, papa!\nTelling lies?\nNo, papa!\nOpen your mouth\nHa, ha, ha!\n\nJohny, Johny\nYes, Papa?\nEating sugar?\nNo, papa!\nTelling lies?\nNo, papa!\nOpen your mouth\nHa, ha, ha!\n\nEnjoy other LooLoo Kids nursery rhymes:\nJohny, Johny Yes Papa https://youtu.be/F4tHL8reNCs\nThe Wheels on the bus https://youtu.be/6X3A-Qe4lPg\nRain, Rain Go Away https://youtu.be/nCqUYAnQF0o\nTen in a Bed https://youtu.be/jk7N3bKvgvg\nFive Little Ducks https://youtu.be/-ccCPcujnys\nAre You Sleeping Brother John https://youtu.be/ptXUH9vhCmA\nPeek-a-Boo https://youtu.be/3pzyUMVI_qQ\nDrawing Song https://youtu.be/4_TANGFW43k\nIf You're Happy and You Know It https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YVCYnfvRLRY\nBaby Shark https://youtu.be/sUxTSW4hW2g\n\nEnjoy educational songs and stories for preschool kids created by experts in children's education!\n\nNursery rhymes in English, canciones en inglés para niños, barnvisorna på engelska, Músicas em inglês para crianças, Gyerekzene, Kinderlieder in Englisch, 英文兒歌, Písničky v angličtině, أناشيد أطفال باللغة الإنجليزية, अंग्रेजी में नर्सरी कविताएं, Comptines en anglais, Lagu-lagu anak berbahasa Inggeris, Musik Untuk Anak, Barnerim på engelsk, Canzoni per bambini in inglese, Engelse kinderliedjes, Piosenki dla dzieci po angielsku, เพลงภาษาอังกฤษสำหรับเด็ก #loolookids #looloonurseryrhymes #loolookids #looloonurseryrhymes #looloo\n\nLooLoo Kids is a registered trademark of MORA TV. For distribution and more information, visit and contact us at https://loolookids.com",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/F4tHL8reNCs/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/F4tHL8reNCs/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/F4tHL8reNCs/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          },
          "standard": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/F4tHL8reNCs/sddefault.jpg",
            "width": 640,
            "height": 480
          },
          "maxres": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/F4tHL8reNCs/maxresdefault.jpg",
            "width": 1280,
            "height": 720
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "LooLoo Kids - Nursery Rhymes and Children's Songs",
        "tags": [
          "johny johny yes papa",
          "johny johny",
          "yes papa",
          "Johny",
          "Johnny",
          "papa",
          "looloo kids",
          "loolookids",
          "looloo",
          "loo loo",
          "johny johny yes papa looloo kids",
          "nursery rhymes",
          "funny",
          "song",
          "songs for children",
          "songs for kids",
          "kids",
          "children",
          "babies",
          "toddlers",
          "little",
          "kindergarten",
          "kindergarten songs",
          "sugar",
          "joni joni",
          "kid songs",
          "children songs",
          "baby songs",
          "songs"
        ],
        "categoryId": "10",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "defaultLanguage": "en",
        "localized": {
          "title": "Johny Johny Yes Papa  THE BEST Song for Children | LooLoo Kids",
          "description": "Johny Jonhy Yes Papa - best song from LooLoo KIDS Nursery Rhymes and Children`s Songs. Download our music app: http://onelink.to/looloo New game with Johny and Friends - https://3novg.app.link/F2ViI5MeNfb\n\nListen on SPOTIFY  - http://listento.loolookids.com/bestofloolookids\nDownload Lea and Pop app: http://onelink.to/leaandpop\n\nSubscribe to our channel if you enjoyed this educational video! You’ll get constant access to more nursery rhymes, more awesome content, so you’ll never miss a chance to show your children new and exciting things! http://BitDotLy.com/Subscribe_to_LooLooKids\n\nFollow us on Facebook for new updates! https://www.facebook.com/LooLooKids/\nTweet to us! https://twitter.com/loolookids\nInstagram: https://instagram.com/loo.loo.kids\n Watch the LooLoo Kids Playlist:  http://BitDotLy.com/310qEOk\n\nJohny Johny Yes Papa Lyrics\n\nJohny, Johny\nYes, Papa?\nEating sugar?\nNo, papa!\nTelling lies?\nNo, papa!\nOpen your mouth\nHa, ha, ha!\n\nJohny, Johny\nYes, Papa?\nEating sugar?\nNo, papa!\nTelling lies?\nNo, papa!\nOpen your mouth\nHa, ha, ha!\n\nEnjoy other LooLoo Kids nursery rhymes:\nJohny, Johny Yes Papa https://youtu.be/F4tHL8reNCs\nThe Wheels on the bus https://youtu.be/6X3A-Qe4lPg\nRain, Rain Go Away https://youtu.be/nCqUYAnQF0o\nTen in a Bed https://youtu.be/jk7N3bKvgvg\nFive Little Ducks https://youtu.be/-ccCPcujnys\nAre You Sleeping Brother John https://youtu.be/ptXUH9vhCmA\nPeek-a-Boo https://youtu.be/3pzyUMVI_qQ\nDrawing Song https://youtu.be/4_TANGFW43k\nIf You're Happy and You Know It https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YVCYnfvRLRY\nBaby Shark https://youtu.be/sUxTSW4hW2g\n\nEnjoy educational songs and stories for preschool kids created by experts in children's education!\n\nNursery rhymes in English, canciones en inglés para niños, barnvisorna på engelska, Músicas em inglês para crianças, Gyerekzene, Kinderlieder in Englisch, 英文兒歌, Písničky v angličtině, أناشيد أطفال باللغة الإنجليزية, अंग्रेजी में नर्सरी कविताएं, Comptines en anglais, Lagu-lagu anak berbahasa Inggeris, Musik Untuk Anak, Barnerim på engelsk, Canzoni per bambini in inglese, Engelse kinderliedjes, Piosenki dla dzieci po angielsku, เพลงภาษาอังกฤษสำหรับเด็ก #loolookids #looloonurseryrhymes #loolookids #looloonurseryrhymes #looloo\n\nLooLoo Kids is a registered trademark of MORA TV. For distribution and more information, visit and contact us at https://loolookids.com"
        },
        "defaultAudioLanguage": "en"
      },
      "statistics": {
        "viewCount": "6493649049",
        "likeCount": "18686604",
        "favoriteCount": "0",
        "commentCount": "0"
      }
    }
  ],
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 3,
    "resultsPerPage": 3
  }
}
```

You can see that there's a lot of cool data there. I ran ten URLs like that with 50 IDs in each, and one more with 34 to get the data on all the videos in the playlist.

I have no way to know how accurate MyTop100Videos' list is, but it looks pretty good. The viewcounts reported for his list range from 11.5 billion down to 517 million.

We get some interesting information from these data. For example, focusing on the "[billion-view club](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_most-viewed_YouTube_videos#Billion-View_Club)" of videos with over a billion views:

- It has 322 members as of the list's last update on July 20, 2022.
- As of today, their time online ranges from 2.8 to 15.6 years, with an average of 7.9.
- 169 of them are Vevo videos.
- They are from 184 channels. The channel with the most videos in the club is [Cocomelon](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbCmjCuTUZos6Inko4u57UQ) with eleven.
- They are in eight categories: 264 in music, 30 in education (mostly for little kids, like [*Baby Shark*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XqZsoesa55w) and those from Cocomelon), 14 in entertainment, 8 in film & animation, 2 each in comedy and people & blogs, and one each in gaming and autos & vehicles.
- Most are in English. I haven't figured out how the codes `defaultLanguage` and `defaultAudioLanguage` work, but it looks like 19 are in Spanish, ten are in Hindi, five in Russian, three in Portugusese, and 60 have no language designation.

So, some pretty interesting information.

Please post another answer if you know a better way of getting these data than by running the Data API on MyTop100Videos' list. Obviously, MyTop100Videos has a way of getting his data, so there has to be a better way of doing this.

Comment: AFAIK [the comments of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71433464) answer to the best your question.